# Theorem counter does not increment

Tags: theorems, amsthm

So this is my code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}
  {\parskip}%                             % Space above
  {\parskip}%                             % Space below
  {\itshape}%                             % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {~---}%                                 % Punctuation after theorem head
  { }%                                    % Space after theorem head
  {}
\theoremstyle{definition}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linktoc=all     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Some Chapter}

\section{Some Section}

\newtheorem{somedef}{Definition}
\begin{somedef}
Some definition
\end{somedef}

\newtheorem{somedef2}{Definition}
\begin{somedef2}
Some other definition
\end{somedef2}

\end{document}
```

I'm compiling this on Overleaf (not sure if it matters) and the link is here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/tsbqtfwbgsvm

Somehow the theorem counter doesn't increase? It shows 1 for both of the definitions.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT: I want the theorems to start from 1 and increment by 1. Shouldn't this be the default behavior anyway?

Comment: But you *are* defining *two* indepedent environments, namely, `somedef` and `somedef2`, each with its independent counter!  **Edit:** what are you actually looking for: 1) two different kinds of theorem, _e.g._, “Theorem” and “Proposition”, that share the same counter, or 2) two *instances* of the same kind of theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is actually this you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}
  {\parskip}%                             % Space above
  {\parskip}%                             % Space below
  {\itshape}%                             % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {~---}%                                 % Punctuation after theorem head
  { }%                                    % Space after theorem head
  {}
\theoremstyle{definition}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linktoc=all     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Some Chapter}

\section{Some Section}

\newtheorem{somedef}{Definition}
\begin{somedef}
Some definition
\end{somedef}

% Do NOT issue a second \newtheorem{somedef2}{Definition}
% Simply reuse the same environment as above:
\begin{somedef}
Some other definition
\end{somedef}

\end{document}
```

Or am I misunderstanding again?

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that you'll have to define a \newtheorem every single time you begin a definition/theorem/etc.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/69818)!  By the way, do you know that you can accept and upvote answers in order to show your appreciation? (:-)

Comment: `\newtheorem` statements should be in the preamble.